# Using Caliburn Micro with Microsoft Ribbon Controls and RibbonApplicationMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, ribbon

I'm trying to use Caliburn Micro and MVVM for a menu. I'm currently using the Ribbon controls located in System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon. Binding the click event using x:Name works ok for regular buttons in a tab, but the menu items in RibbonApplicationMenu does not work. Is that a bug or do I have to do some extra work in the bootstrapper class to make sure that CM finds the RibbonApplicationMenuItems? I'm on CM v2.0.1.

Some example here:

XAML:

```
<Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" >
    <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="F">
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="{Binding NewText}" x:Name="AppNew" />
        </RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <RibbonTab Header="{Binding OverviewTabText}" >
        <RibbonGroup x:Name="MainGroupOverview" Header="{Binding MainGroupText}">
            <RibbonButton Label="{Binding NewText}" x:Name="AppNewOverview"  />
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

And in ViewModel class:

```
public void AppNew()
{
    //this will not be called
    New();
}

public void AppNewOverview()
{
    //this works just fine
    New();
}
```

Comment: Because the items are not in the visual tree menuitem related it is probably having issues finding a method to execute.  I assume you click and nothing happens? Cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext = "{Binding path=DataContext, ElementName=Ribbon}" place that on the applicationmenu.

Comment: Yes I click and nothing happens. Seems like CM does not traverse all nodes in the tree? Or in this case it is a sub tree "ApplicationMenu" that has its own tree, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: its a problem for how CM gets templates and or context menus (like your case), that Action dependency object in the above code should work. That are not immediately visible on the Visual Tree

Comment: Tried that on <RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="F"> and <RibbonApplicationMenuItem> node with no success. What might be the problem?

Comment: Still digging on this but for the name attributed doesn't seem to work for anything, actually mocked up a sample on my end.  cm:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action NewApp()]" works.  Actually strange and you might want to drop by the GitHub repo and fill out if this might actually be an issue.

Comment: Thank you mvermef for your input, the last comment did the trick. This might however be an issue for the CM team and I will post at their github. Please make the last comment as an answer and I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still digging on this but for the name attributed doesn't seem to work for anything, actually mocked up a sample on my end. cm:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action NewApp()]" works. Actually strange and you might want to drop by the GitHub repo and fill out if this might actually be an issue. –